# Why is my Canon's shutter speed so slow in bright light conditions?

Tags: canon, dslr, exposure, troubleshooting, shutter-speed

My Canon 5D Mark 1, which has been in use for about 10 years, is strange.  If you use Av mode or Auto mode, the shutter speed is very slow even when there is enough light. Even taking direct pictures of the sun is very slow. Even if I increase the ISO to H2, it does not go down to less than 1 second. However, if I cover the lens with my hand to create a dark situation, it becomes fine again.

What is the problem? Internal exposure meter? Or an internal circuit problem?

Comment: Please upload the same scene in both Av and Tv modes, including the shutter speed, aperture and ISO for each - thanks.

Comment: Is this happen when you use viewfinder? What happen when you use liveview?

Comment: Have you tried using a different lens?

Comment: I second the suggestion to try a different lens. This problem sounds very strange to me, but I could imagine that the lens communicates a wrong focal length to the body